# Properly defining a monad class

Tags: haskell, monads

How do I make following declaration of a list monad compilable?

```
module Main where

instance Monad m where
  -- "return" constructs a one-item list.
  return x = [x]
  -- "bind" concatenates the lists obtained by applying f to each item in list xs.
  xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
  -- The zero object is an empty list.
  mzero = []
```

Currently I get the following error:

```
monad_ex1.hs:9:3: ‘mzero’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Monad’
```

My code is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Collections , goal is to run create compilable code from that, import it in ghci and play around with it.

Removing mzero from the code leads to another cryptic message:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Monad m’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monad m’
```

Comment: As the error says, monads don't have a "zero object" or `mzero`.

Comment: `instance Monad m` would make all possible types `m` an instance of `Monad`. You'd need `instance Monad []`, but that already exists in the standard library. You have to define either your own class or your own type to be able to provide an instance like this.

Comment: It's not clear for me why did you add that 'mzero' while defining an instance for monad type class..

Comment: How would I define custom Monad. My code is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Collections, I want to simply run those in haskell and try to populate them. See edit.

Comment: @kaboom Your second error is what my second comment is all about.

Comment: The code on wikipedia is just random samples from the standard library (`Control.Monad` and friends). You can't repeat it in your code; it's already defined.

Comment: ok, where can I read on how to define simplest monad of my own, with custom name to it. In all the tutorials there is class Monad m defined, and then it's never used. I'm very confused on how to just declare one.

Comment: Well, first you need to define a parametrized type. A simple example is something equivalent to the standard `Maybe` type: `data Option a = None | Some a`. Then you can do `instance Monad Option where { return x = ...; m >>= f = ... }` (implementation left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: "In all the tutorials there is class Monad m defined, and then it's never used" -- You are mixing up the definition of a class (e.g. `Monad`) with the definition of instances of that class (e.g. `[]`, `Maybe`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few potential pitfalls here, most of which are covered in the comments:

- There is no `mzero` defined for `Monad` instances, and you'll get an error if you try to specify one.  `mzero` would be defined in the `MonadPlus` instance, if any.
- Trying to redefine the monad instance for built-in lists won't work.  You need to define your own `List` type if you want to play with this.
- In "modern" Haskell (since GHC 7.10), the implementation of the [Applicative => Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) has obsoleted a lot of old Monad tutorials and made user-defined Monads a little more difficult to write because you also need to define `Functor` and `Applicative` instances ([detailed migration instructions](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Migration/7.10#base-4.8.0.0)).

So, here is a translation of your list example to use a user-defined `List` type with GHC 7.10-compatible boilerplate.  Note that the definition for `return` gets moved into the `Applicative` instance's `pure` instead.

```
module MyListMonad where

import Control.Monad

data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor List where
  fmap = liftM                      -- boilerplate
instance Applicative List where
  pure x = Cons x Empty             -- put definition of `return` here
  (<*>) = ap 
instance Monad List where
  return = pure                     -- boilerplate
  (>>) = (*>)                       -- boilerplate
  xs >>= f = myConcat (myMap f xs)  -- bind definition here

myConcat :: List (List a) -> List a
myConcat (Cons lst rest) = myAppend lst (myConcat rest)
myConcat Empty = Empty

myAppend :: List a -> List a -> List a
myAppend (Cons x rest) ys = Cons x (myAppend rest ys)
myAppend Empty ys = ys

myMap :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
myMap f (Cons x rest) = Cons (f x) (myMap f rest)
myMap _ Empty = Empty

test = do x <- Cons 1 $ Cons 2 $ Cons 3 Empty
          y <- Cons 4 $ Cons 5 $ Empty
          return (x * y)
```